# Forms Runner form - warning displayed when navigating to another page, tick and save buttons appear automatically

Tags: orbeon

I have a form which I created using Forms Builder - this form displays a tick mark and a floppy icon (for save) at the bottom.  I do not want those displayed since there is no persistence being performed using those buttons in my code.  How to achieve this (no display of those icons) - I have already done

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.*" value="" />
```

and

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.view.*.*" value="back pdf" />
```

in my local properties file

Also, I direct the user to another page using the xforms:load action - that results in the floppy icon being shown (detection that instance has changed perhaps) and also shows an alert confirming if I really want to navigate away from the page.  How do I disable this warning (instance data will change, but I do not want the floppy/save icon in the first place)...

[edit1]
Based on suggestions:

Since what I want is no button at all (on the initial form, actions are taken based on what the user selected in select1), I did:

```
...</fr:body><fr:buttons /></fr:view>...
```

but that does not help (tick and floppy icons still appear).  I also did

```
<xforms:action ev:event="xforms-select" target="XMLOptions-control"
                   if="event('xxforms:item-value')='RETRIEVE'">
        <!-- workaround to stop showing the alert asking the user if they really want to move away from the page -->
        <xforms:setvalue ref="xxforms:instance('fr-persistence-instance')/data-safe">true</xforms:setvalue>
        <xforms:load show="replace" resource="/fr/prototype/retrieval/new"/>
    </xforms:action>
```

That does not help either (the alert dialog continues to be shown).  I cannot see any instance named 'fr-persistence-instance' in my xforms source.

Answer (score 2):

Your first property is the correct one to remove all the buttons in the detail page:

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.*" value=""/>
```

But it looks to me that what you want to do is to add your own custom buttons, instead of using the default ones. Instead of changing the `oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.*` property, you can edit the form source and place your own buttons there in `<fr:buttons>`. See the section "Including standard buttons" on [Create a wizard or multi-page form with Form Builder](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/form-builder-wizard).

To avoid the message asking users if they really want to navigate away from the current page, before the `<xforms:load>`, do:

```
<xforms:setvalue ref="xxforms:instance('fr-persistence-instance')/data-safe-override">true</xforms:setvalue>
```

For instance, you would put this in your own button:

```
<fr:buttons>
    <fr:button>
        <xforms:label>Go to Orbeon</xforms:label>
        <xforms:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
            <xforms:setvalue ref="xxforms:instance('fr-persistence-instance')/data-safe-override">true</xforms:setvalue>
            <xforms:load resource="http://www.orbeon.com/"/>
        </xforms:action>
    </fr:button>
</fr:buttons>
```

To hide the status icons telling you if the data is valid, you can use the following CSS (and see [styling](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/styling) for more information on how to add your own CSS):

```
.fr-status-icons { display: none }
```

Comment: Good point: sorry, the element you need to set to true is `data-safe-override`. I updated my answer, put an example of button, and a note about the CSS you can use to hide the status icons.